# FormPanel class: how do I add a textbox name (not inside it, but at left side) and order the buttons?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script

I create this google apps script formPanel:

[image]

With this code:

```
function getClemencyParameters() {
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   var form = app.createFormPanel().setTitle("My text box visible title");
   var flow = app.createFlowPanel();
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox").setText("SetText"));
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox2").setTitle("SetTitle"));
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox3"));
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setName("textBox4"));  
   flow.add(app.createListBox().setName("listBox").addItem("option 1").addItem("option 2"));
   flow.add(app.createListBox().setName("listBox").addItem("option 1").addItem("option 2"));
   flow.add(app.createListBox().setName("listBox").addItem("option 1").addItem("option 2"));
   flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Submit"));
   form.add(flow);
   app.add(form);

   spreadsheet.show(app);
 }
```

But I'd like to put a label at the left side of each textbox (which doesn't has the method `createLabel`) and put each one bellow the other. How do I add the textbox name (not inside it, but at left side) and order the buttons? (in the textBox and formPanel class documentation I didn't found nothing)

Comment: Is there a special reason you use a flowpanel ?  Why not a grid or a flex panel?

Comment: No special reason. What do you think would be more appropriate @Sergeinsas, could you give me more one hint in the trigger question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the option of using vertical and horizontal panels can be an acceptable solution for you, or is there any particular reason not to do so?
If not, here is a simple solution:

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); // you can embed that in a form panel

  var qZeroPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var txt = app.createTextBox().setId("qZero").setName("qZero").setValue("test");
  qZeroPanel.add(app.createLabel("question zero':")).add(txt);

  var qOnePanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  qOnePanel.add(app.createLabel("question one:")).
  add(app.createListBox().
      addItem("anwser 1").
      addItem("answer 2").
      addItem("answer 3").
      setName("qOne"));
  var qTwoPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  qTwoPanel.add(app.createLabel("question two:")).add(app.createListBox().addItem("anwser 1").addItem("answer 2").addItem("answer 3").setName("qTwo"));

  var handlerBut = app.createServerHandler("butAnswer").addCallbackElement(panel);
  var but = app.createButton("submit").setId("submitButton").addClickHandler(handlerBut);
  panel.add(qZeroPanel).add(qOnePanel).add(qTwoPanel).add(but).add(app.createLabel().setId("answer"));
  app.add(panel);
  return(app);
}

function butAnswer(e){
  var qOne = e.parameter.qOne;
  var qZero = e.parameter.qZero;
  var qTwo = e.parameter.qTwo;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById("answer").setText("you entered: qZero: "+qZero+", qOne: "+qOne+", qTwo: "+qTwo);
  return(app);
}
```

Hoping it help you,
Harold